# Fix scroll position in place when setting body to position:fixed (ios)

Tags: jquery, ios, scroll, webkit, fixed

Ok, so I have a page with a button which activates an overlay using jQuery. In order to prevent the content behind the overlay from scrolling on devices such as iPhone, I am using the following code to toggle the class of 'body' to one which is set to position: fixed, overlay: hidden.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter-btn, .close-filter").click(function(){
        $("body").toggleClass("fix");
    });
});
</script>
```

This works, except for the fact that when the button is clicked to activate the overlay, the page returns to the top which is not what I want - I would like the current scroll position to remain.

I'm guessing I need to use some JS here to get the scroll position and fix it in place, and then disabling that when the overlay is closed. Thing is, I'm not sure how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The body would "scroll" to the top because it is being fixed to the top.

Try:

```
$('html, body').css({'overflow': $('html, body').css('overflow')=='hidden'?'auto':'hidden'});
```

Comment: I've already tried setting both html and body to overflow hidden without 'fixing' either of them (which it looks like your code is doing), but the problem still occurs. It's as soon as overflow is set to hidden the page only wants to show the top portion.

Comment: Just try removing the `$("body").toggleClass("fix");` and replace it with the code I provided.